# Angularjs error: Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'testParent', required by directive 'testChildren', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, directive

Env first: angularjs 1.2 rc1

I need two directive: parent & children, so I use **require: true**, but I meet a problem:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'testParent', required by directive 'testChildren', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$compile/ctreq?p0=testParent&p1=testChildren
    at http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular.js:78:12
    at getControllers (http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular.js:4981:19)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular.js:5122:35)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular.js:4640:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular.js:5115:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular.js:4640:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular.js:4549:30)
    at http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular-route.js:854:15
    at publicLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular.js:4548:29)
    at update (http://127.0.0.1/static/lib/angular/1.2.0rc2/angular-route.js:832:13) <div test-children="">
```

My code is simple(just 4 test):

```
angular.module('app', [])


.directive('testParent', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function link(scope, element, attr) {
            element.addClass('abcdef')
        }
    }
}])

.directive('testChildren', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^testParent',

        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            // console.log(ctrl)
                // ctrl.setTest('It is test')
                element.append('inner text')
        }
    }
}])
```

***Who can tell me what happen???***

Comment: The HTML template for this?

Answer (score 1):

the parent directive must provide a controller, this is then passed in as the optional 4th parameter on the link function of the child

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('testParent', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: function() { 
            //... must include a controller in parent 
            this.doSomething = () => {}
        }
    }
}])

.directive('testChildren', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^testParent',

        link: function(scope, element, attr, parent) {
            parent.doSomething()
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: I am having this exact same problem in v1.4.8.  I have provided a controller for the parent directive.  I have exposed that controller within the module with `.controller(...)`.  I am still getting this error.

I look forward to seeing this answered with working example code.